# CakePHP: Auth issue, suddenly can't login anymore, password query does not match database

Tags: cakephp

While developing my app, I suddenly can't login using Auth anymore, according to Cake, the password or username is not correct.

When I track the query, the password (hashed) that Cake is looking for is not the one that the user has. I matched the query password to the User table in MAMP.

What can be the reason of this sudden error? What can Cake make looking for another password that not exists in the user table.

- all error logs are clear
- I can register a user without any issue
- I use everything the standard Cake way (Auth, register process etc)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

well, most likely, you changed the salt value in core.php or hash mehod, or both. That's the only 2 reasons the hash is different for the same password.

Comment: Thanks. I am 300% sure I did not touch these values.

Comment: the app is in localhost, right? And no one has changed the password?

Comment: It is getting weirder. I deleted the whole database and recreated it. When I use my gmail to register, all goes well. It only happens with 1 specific email adress. The hashed password during login is always the same one and does not match any password in the database. However, when I reset the password with the reset_password function, I can reset the password via email and I can login with this specific email address again. I will check out what is happening here, very strange and appears to be unstable.

Comment: I'd say, check your register function. Cake most likely won't discriminate against your email :))